# Javascript: get driving distance and time and show current location in google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using the following codes to get driving distance and time and display the current location in Google map using javascript.

The values of longitude and latitude and post codes etc comes from php/mysql.

Everything works fine.

However, the issue that I have is that something stops the javascript codes to work together on the same page and they only work if they are in separate pages!

So basically I can only use one of the Javascript codes in a page and if I use both codes in the same page, the only code that works would be the driving distance and time code which I have no idea why.

**here is my driving distance and time calculation code:**

```
<script>
    (function () {


        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
            createMap = function (start) {
                var travel = {
                        origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
                        destination : "<?php echo $CUpostCode; ?>",
                        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                        // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
                    },
                    mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 10,
                        // Default view: downtown Stockholm
                        center : new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
                directionsService.route(travel, function(result, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            };

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {



                window.onload = (function (position) {
                        // Success!
                        createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                        });
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                        createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
            else {
                // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
                createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                });


            }
    })();
</script>
```

**and this is the code for showing the Location in the google map:**

```
<script>
    function showCurrentLocation(position)
    {
        var latitude = <?php echo $curLat; ?>;
        var longitude = <?php echo $curLon; ?>;
        var coords2 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords2,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //create the map, and place it in the HTML map div
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("mapPlaceholder"), mapOptions2
    );

    //place the initial marker
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords2,
    map: map2,
    title2: "Current location!"
    });
    }
</script>
```

and I have these two lines in my page's header:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.se/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could someone please let me know whats the conflict between these two codes that stops them working in the same page?

Comment: which is the working script when you have both? (If there is one)

Comment: What do you mean by they don't work together?  They seem to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/1on2yumf/).

Comment: @faby, the first lot of code (the distance and time calculator) works when I put both codes in the same page. when I remove the distance calculator code from my page, the map works.

Comment: @geocodezip, no they don't work together. there should be two different maps.. one for distance calculator (the one that's showing in your example) and another one for current location which is my second lot of codes.

Comment: It works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1on2yumf/1/), how are you calling `showCurrentLocation`?

Comment: @william be sure that showCurrentLocation is called, another thing give always width and height css property to the div where the map should be. Maybe it is there but you don't see it.

Comment: @geocodezip, thanks mate. I was calling it like so: onload="showCurrentLocation()" but i did call it your way now: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',showCurrentLocation);  and everyhting works fine...

Comment: @faby, cheers buddy. I did have the css width and height but i was calling the function in the body tag and i think that was causing the issue.

Comment: The problem was you were overwriting the onload event, but there was no way to guess that without a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you didn't provide.

Comment: @geocodezip, sorry pal.. I will provide an example in jsfiddle from now on..

Comment: A StackOverflow code snippet that demonstrates the issue would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You added: I was calling it like so: onload="showCurrentLocation()"

you are overwriting the onload event.  Using `google.maps.addDomListener` instead will solve that issue.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',showCurrentLocation);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1on2yumf/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
var curLat = 45;
var curLon = -117;

(function () {


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
        createMap = function (start) {
            var travel = {
                origin: (start.coords) ? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
                destination: "07646",
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
            },
            mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                // Default view: downtown Stockholm
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
            directionsService.route(travel, function (result, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        };

    // Check for geolocation support    
    if (navigator.geolocation) {



        window.onload = (function (position) {
            // Success!
            createMap({
                coords: true,
                //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                //lng : position.coords.longitude


                lat: curLat,
                lng: curLon
            });
        },

        function () {
            // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
            createMap({
                coords: true,
                //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                //lng : position.coords.longitude


                lat: curLat,
                lng: curLon
            });
        });
    } else {
        // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
        createMap({
            coords: true,
            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
            //lng : position.coords.longitude


            lat: curLat,
            lng: curLon
        });


    }
})();

function showCurrentLocation(position) {
    var latitude = curLat;
    var longitude = curLon;
    var coords2 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords2,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //create the map, and place it in the HTML map div
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("mapPlaceholder"), mapOptions2);

    //place the initial marker
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords2,
        map: map2,
        title2: "Current location!"
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',showCurrentLocation);
```

```css
html, body, #map, #map-directions, #mapPlaceholder {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="mapPlaceholder" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="map" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="map-directions"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```